# What's this IPA symbol under the t: [t̬]?

Tags: ipa

This is the IPA for "better": /ˈbet̬.ɚ/

What's the little arrow mark under the "t"?

Is it emphasis? Or something else?

Comment: https://pronuncian.com/when-t-doesnt-sound-like-t Googled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a diacritic sign which indicates that the sound is voiced.

You might have noticed that in American English, a *t* is pronounced something like a *d* (voiced) when it's flanked by vowels in an unstressed syllable. So *better* sounds like *bedder*. However, that is not exactly a *d*, but something called an alveolar flap, represented by [ɾ] in the IPA.

Dictionaries don't often use IPA and writing a *d* in transcriptions can be confusing at times, therefore they write a small caron diacritic under the symbol to indicate that it's voiced.

- *better* → [ˈbɛɾɚ] or [ˈbɛt̬.ɚ]
- *water* → [ˈwɑːɾɚ] [ˈwɑːt̬ɚ]

I think it's partly because the voiced sound is an allophone of /t/ and is not exactly a /d/.

We also have a voiceless diacritic, a small circle. For instance, '*... shoes for...*' could be transcribed as [...ʃuːz̥fə...], the z gets devoiced in anticipation of the following voiceless sound (f).

Comment: Although it's not identical to /d/, my understanding is that most Americans also flap their "d"s in the same position.

Comment: @rjpond: Yes. Most flap their r's too. It's really a single sound [ɾ], but I guess Dictionaries use [t̬] for convenience. [CED](https://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/reader) uses /d/ for 'reader'... they're inconsistent too.